# Best practice to implement JpaRepository

Tags: java, database, spring, interface, spring-data-jpa

What is the best practice to implement JpaRepository?

```
public interface XRepository implements JpaRepository<X, Long> {
   @Query(".....")
   X findByY(@Param("yId") Long yId);
}
```

Is it exists any way to skip implementation of this method in non abstract class, which implements XRepository?

As I know, Java says NO.

Comment: first of all if you use findBy... U dont need query, it should be done automatically. U dont need implement anything, u just neee to declare method with params and return value. That is all

Comment: XXXRepository is NOTHING to do with the JPA API. That is Spring Data JPA, a totally different API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to implement this interface. Include the following annotations and extend the basic interface:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
```

For example:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
public interface CitizenRepository extends JpaRepository<Citizen, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Citizen c WHERE c.idGame=?1")
    Citizen findByGameId(int gameId);
}
```

Comment: I mean, if I use not Java 9+ and need private methods, so I need to implement it.

Comment: I know, I am talking about specifix case, if I need private methods.